# Rails state machine error when executing gem (Errno::EINVAL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, state-machine

An error occurs when I execute this command:

```
c:\gem install state_machines
```

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
>       Invalid argument - c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/state_machines-0.2.2/test/unit/node_collection/node_collection_after_being_copied_test

Comment: I am trying on windows machine

Answer (score 4):

This fixed my problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/jeff-hamm/state_machines

cd state_machines

bundle gem state_machines

rake install
```